# Can a metamagic cost reduction be applied to Heighten Spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, metamagic

Since [Heighten Spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#heighten-spell) actually increases the level of the spell, can it's metamagic level adjustment be reduced by traits like [Magical Lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage) or feats like [Spell Perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection)?

Comment: Because you can reduce the cost of metamagic level adjustment? If it's just a 2nd level spell you can't reduce the spell slot required to cast it.

Comment: The description of Heighten Spell is very vague, as it is worded you can cast a Quickened Heightened Fireball with a lvl7 slot with an effective spell level of 7. Am I the only one not to play like that ?

Answer (score 3):

## No

From the text that you linked to,

> A heightened spell has a higher spell level than normal (up to a maximum of 9th level). Unlike other metamagic feats, Heighten Spell actually increases the effective level of the spell that it modifies... **The heightened spell is as difficult to prepare and cast as a spell of its effective level**.

They are simply higher level spells in every respect - they do not take up a spell slot that is even higher than their effective level.

Comment: The question has been edited, so this answer no longer applies.